# np.dot(function, array) returns error - evaluating a cubic spline at a point

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working on a cubic spline interpolation project.

I have created the following function which extracts the coefficient matrix of a cubic spline.

```
def coeff(x,y):
    cs = CubicSpline(x,y,bc_type='natural')
    a = cs.c
    coeff_matrix = a.transpose()
    print(coeff_matrix)
    return

#Test for f(x)=x^2 over 5 data points 
x = np.linspace(0,4,5)
y = x**2
#coeff(x,y)
```

I need now to write a function, which evaluates the spline at xval. I realise this can be done simply by cs(xval) but it must be a function of the form yval=cubsplineval(coeff,x,xval). My attempt is below...

```
xval=3.5
t=np.full((1,len(x)),3.5)
z=t-x
np.dot(coeff(x,y), z)
```

But the np.dot(coeff(x,y), z) throws up the error "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'". Not sure how to correct this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `coeff()` function needs to *actually return its calculated value* to be of any use here, rather than just printing it.

Comment: Of course! Been starring at it for over an hour. Thank you @jasonharper